# Will an Acer Aspire One run RootsMagic 4

Tags: acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire One notebook (XP/1GB Memory/160GB HDC).  Will it run RootsMagic 4 (it required a 64 MB RAM/160MB Hard drive space)  -  I also need it to run my e-mail and Word documents.

Comment: How do you run e-mail?  I thought you read it.  And running word documents?  Those are the ones that contain viruses aren't they? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on those specs, you have more than enough capacity.

```
  1 GB  =  15.625  *   64 MB
160 GB  ~  1000    *  160 MB
```